# kivy isn't able to display certain unicode characters properly

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, kivy

im trying to Create Label with name of 'გიორგი' but kivy Dont recognize characters im Using 'utf-8'

````
class Admin(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class AdminApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Admin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AdminApp().run()```
````

Label:
            text: 'გიო'

```
Label:
            text: 'გიო'
```

output is ??? 3 Question marks any help pls

Answer (score 4):

Add an attribute, `font_name` to override the default *Roboto* fonts. Use *DejaVu Sans* fonts.

## Example

### main.py

```
 -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
#:import sp kivy.metrics.sp
Label:
    text: 'გიო'
    font_size: sp(50)
    font_name: "DejaVuSans.ttf"
"""))
```